# Behavior of int x[size]={0}

Tags: c, arrays

I am reading through K&R 2nd Edition and C by Dissection 4th Edition, and came to arrays where they both didn't explicitly state it but I remember from a class that we want to always initialize an array to zero to circumvent garbage being in the indices from previous memory allocations.

I looked online and similar suggestions were made, but I saw an array declaration/initialization I hadn't seen before so I wanted to test it: `int x[size]={0};` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416754/why-do-we-need-initialize-an-array-to-0-null#comment7527196_6417016)

I wrote a little c program to check things out, and I'm currently going down the rabbit hole it seems.

Can someone please help explain the output?

gcc is compiling to c99, -std=c89 won't compile (because of // type comments so I know it isn't c89 (ansi) ), but looking at the gcc flags I cannot find **STDC_VERSION** flag to tell me which is; therefore, I've manually compiled like: **gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o arrayTest arrayTest.c**

The little program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 2
#define DEBUG_ true


int main()
{

    int x[5] ={0};// what does this do? Guess: Initialize x[0]-x[4] values of 0?
    int i=0;// for loop

    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    if(DEBUG_){
       printf("TESTING FOR NULLITY OF INDICES\n");
       for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          if(x[i]==NULL) printf("The Value at %d is NULL\n", i);
       }// If each is null, thats what int x[5]={0} decl/initl does..
        // Is 0 NULL in C Language (I wouldn't have thought so..)
    }

    printf("assigning 0 to all indices of the array..\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){ x[i]=0; }
    // assigning the array to zeros..

    if(DEBUG_){
       printf("printing contents of array after filling with zero's\n");
       for(i=0; i<5; i++){ printf(x[i]+"\n"); }
       // hopefully print out 5 zeros..
       printf("SUSPECTING THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN    ARRAY\n");
       for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          if(x[i]==NULL) printf("The Value at %d is NULL\n", i);
      }
    }

    printf("Filling the array, each index has value i*2\n");
   for(i=0; i<5; i++){ x[i]= i*2; }
   // initialize the array to i*2.
   // Expected Values 0, 2, 4, 6, 8

   for(i=0; i<5; i++){ printf(x[i]+"\n"); }
   // hopefully print out Expected Values

    return 0;
}
```

The output from the program:

```
-bash-4.3$
-bash-4.3$ arrayTest
Hello, World!
TESTING FOR NULLITY OF INDICES
The Value at 0 is NULL
The Value at 1 is NULL
The Value at 2 is NULL
The Value at 3 is NULL
The Value at 4 is NULL
assigning 0 to all indices of the array..
printing contents of array after filling with zero's





SUSPECTING THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAY
The Value at 0 is NULL
The Value at 1 is NULL
The Value at 2 is NULL
The Value at 3 is NULL 
The Value at 4 is NULL
Filling the array, each index has value i*2

USPECTING THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAYPECTING THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAYCTING THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAY
```

From the looks of that last line there is a repeating sequence occurring:

- **USPECTING** THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAY
- **PECTING** THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAY
- **CTING** THAT ZERO FILL DIDN'T REPLACE NULL VALUES IN ARRAY

I am not sure why this is occurring.

Specifically can someone explain what the array declaration/initialization actually does, why assigning zeros to the array isn't working in this case, why trying to set each index to `i*2` doesn't work, and what is going on with the print pattern at the end of the output?

Comment: With `printf(x[i]+"\n")`, you are attempting to print a string that starts `x[i]` characters after the beginning of the string `"\n"` in memory. This generally yields undefined behavior. There is no guarantee as to what data resides at that place in memory, or even if that memory is accessible for read operations (let alone, if that memory address is valid to begin with).

Comment: To make it worse, since `printf` expects a null-terminated string as its first argument, it might be scanning that memory for a "long time" before encountering the null-character (possibly performing a memory access violation somewhere along the way).

Comment: `int x[5] ={0};` -- Explicitly sets `x[0]` to `0`; implicitly sets all unspecified elements to `0` as well. ... `if(x[i]==NULL)` -- Don't do this. `x[i]` is an `int`, not a pointer. It's likely to compile and work, because `NULL` is *probably* defined as `0`, but it's meant to be used as a null pointer constant. There are no pointer objects in your program.

Comment: `typedef int bool;` -- In C99 and later, this is unnecessary; `bool` is defined in `<stdbool.h>`. `#define false 2` -- This is wrong, if you need to define `false` yourself it should be `0`. If you change `#define DEBUG_ true` to `#define DEBUG_ false`, the debugging code will still be executed. See section 9 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) for more information on Boolean expressions and variables in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're right, I'm not sure why in this case I had `#define false 2`, obviously wrong. I keep `typedef int bool;` in the code just because sometimes for school I have to compile with a different compiler (depends what the professor wants.); otherwise, I would have to change the code to be executed depending on the compiler- unless there is another way around that?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Is there ever a valid reason to check if a variable's value is `NULL`? I know about checking if a pointer is `NULL` to prevent `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION` but what if I read in a value from an outside source and assign it to a variable- wouldn't I want to check to make sure that value isn't a null value before I use it?

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding: It can make sense to check whether a variable's value is `NULL` **if and only if** that variable is a pointer. You don't normally read pointer values from an outside source.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Your usage of dual implication seems to infer that only referenced objects are nullable in C- meaning primitives can never be null. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding: C doesn't have a concept of "nullable". Each pointer type has a distinct value, the *null pointer* of that type, that doesn't point to any object (or function). There's also a *null character* value, `'\0'`, which is not the same thing. There is no "null" value for type `int`, for example;  `0` is just another value integer value. Due to some historic quirks, if you write something like `int n = NULL;`, the compiler will likely fail to warn you that you're doing something silly; if it compiles, it will merely set `n` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The `printf()` usage is wrong here. Change

```
printf(x[i]+"\n");
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", x[i]);
```

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for details.

Also, regarding the initializaion, if you need any reference, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626436/2173917).

Comment: I fixed it and everything works fine now except `if(x[i]==NULL)` is always true (before and after I fill it with zeros.) I'm assuming that this isn't the way to check nullity of an array index in C?

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding what do you mean by NULLity? usually NULL is used for pointers, not as a variable value. Usually, it is a 0, casted to `void *`, but that's not something you should be using. Use a simple `0` for variable values.

Comment: I see. Thank you. In another language sometimes the initialization of a variable is NULL by default by the compiler if it wasn't explicitly initialized to a value. I'm not sure where I'm remembering that, perhaps Java or PhP, but I just wanted to check if the value held in the index was null or zero.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

This means that in this declaration

```
int x[5] ={0};
```

the first element of the array is explicitly initialized by 0 and all other elements of the array are implicitly initialized the same way as objects with static storage duration that is they are also initialized by 0.

If you would wriite for example

```
int x[5] ={1};
```

then the elements of the array would be initialized like { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

Also take into account that this statement

```
printf(x[i]+"\n");
```

does not do what you expect. In this expression  `x[i]+"\n"` there is used the pointer arithmetic becuase string literal `"\n"` is converted to pointer to its first character and after adding to the pointer value `x[i]` can result in undefined behaviour. I think you mean

```
printf( "%d\n", x[i] );
```

Here is a more interesting example of initializing odd elements of an array with 1 and even elements with 0 which you do not know yet..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { [1] = 1, [3] = 1, [5] = 1 };

    printf( "The number of elements in the array is %zu\n", 
            sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The number of elements in the array is 6
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Thus if for example you want to initialize only the last element of an array with 1 and all other elements with 0 you can write

```
int a[] = { [4] = 1 };
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for that example and for the explanation behind what was going on with the pointer arithmetic in my improper `printf()` statement. I will +1 when I can.